# jQuery add link to text in every row cell from url on another cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has a table of many entries from Special Offers that are loaded using csv export to my site and then I display those offers in a table.

My problem is that csv export does not include the link of the boat that's in the title, so I have added the link at the end of the google sheet table so I can then use jquery to get the value of the cell and replace the text of the boat title to include the boat name along with the link.

Here's the google sheet. The URL I want to get is at the **I** column; and I then replace the text at the **B** column with the original text that has the link from column **I**.
[image]

It does work kinda, but it puts all the links from every cell in the  tag like so:
[image]

Here's the code I use that needs revamp:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#create_tables td:nth-child(2)').html(function(){
        return '<a href="' + $('#create_tables td:nth-child(9)').text() + '" target="_blank">' + $(this).text() + '</a>';
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need each and closest to navigate from one cell to a sibling cell

```
$('#create_tables td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
  const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  const url = $row.find("td").eq(8).text(); // nth-child is 1 based, .eq 0 based
  $(this).html(`<a href="${url}" target="_blank">${this.textContent}</a>`);
})
```

Comment: Well, I changed the code according to what you said, it creates a link but the link href is blank:

`$('#create_tables td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
  const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  const url = $row.find("td").eq(9).text();
  $(this).html('<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + $(this).text() + '</a>');
});`

Comment: Never mind, it worked, I had to change the eq(9) to eq(8)...